# How to combine an Rxjs timer with a manual user action

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable that polls every 60 seconds.  However, if user makes an action (i.e. success from another API call) in the component level I'd like to trigger that API call again but keep the polling going on.  How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far for the polling:

```
this.covidCases$ = timer(1, 60000).pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        this.covidService.getCovidCases().pipe(
          map(data => {
            return data.cases;
          }),
        ),
      ),
      retry(),
      shareReplay(1),
    );
```

I then pass this observable to the component:

```
<case-list [covidCases]="covidCases$"></case-list>
```

Comment: you can merge another observable with timer.so subscribed function will run for timer and other observable .Then you can trigger the other observable by just calling next.https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge

Answer (score 0):

I think a `Subject` + `merge` would fit your need:

```
import { interval, Subject, merge } from 'rxjs'; 
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

const first = interval(1000);
const subject = new Subject();

var userAction = () => {
  // make some api call then when resolved
  subject.next('manual action!')
}

//emit outputs from all observables
const example = merge(
  first.pipe(mapTo('FIRST!')),
  subject.asObservable()
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nc26kmzd/3/)

Comment: nice! however how do I do this if Im passing the observable to the component? The actino takes place in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge). Sample code:

```
    const btn = document.getElementById('save');
    const source = fromEvent(btn, 'click');
    const example = source.pipe(map(event => `Event time: ${event.timeStamp}`));
    // merging button click and timer. Update it to suit your needs
    const raceTest = merge(timer(1, 5000).pipe(map(x => 'Hello')), example);
    raceTest.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```